# Using quicksort algorithm to sort an array of integers with duplicate values

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

I'm trying to complete a project for school using C# that asks a user to input the length of an array and then has them fill in the array with integers. The array then needs to be sorted using a quicksort algorithm to put them in order of lowest to highest. My code is doing this successfully, but doesn't work if the user enters any duplicate values into the array.

For example:

- an array of [4,7,2,3,9] sorts just fine.
- an array of [4,7,2,7,9] wont sort because of the duplicate 7.

I'm wondering if anyone has an idea of how to handle duplicates if they are entered. Please keep in mind I'm still learning so any help is appreciated. The code so far is listed below

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    namespace Quicksort
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static void Quick_Sort(int[] arr, int left, int right)
            {
                if (left < right)
                {
                    int pivot = Partition(arr, left, right);

                    if (pivot > 1)
                    {
                        Quick_Sort(arr, left, pivot - 1);
                    }
                    if (pivot + 1 < right)
                    {
                        Quick_Sort(arr, pivot + 1, right);
                    }
                }
            }
            private static int Partition(int[] arr, int left, int right)
            {
                int pivot = arr[left];
                while (true)
                {

                    while (arr[left] < pivot)
                    {
                        left++;
                    }
                    while (arr[right] > pivot)
                    {
                        right--;
                    }
                    if (left < right)
                    {
                        if (arr[left] == arr[right]) return right;
                        int temp = arr[left];
                        arr[left] = arr[right];
                        arr[right] = temp;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return right;
                    }
                }
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Console.Write("\nProgram for sorting a numeric array using Quick Sorting");
                Console.Write("\n\nEnter number of elements: ");
                int max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int[] arr = new int[max];

                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)

                {
                    Console.Write("\nEnter [" + (i + 1).ToString() + "] element: ");
                    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Original array : ");
                foreach (var item in arr)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + item);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                Quick_Sort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Sorted array : ");
                foreach (var item in arr)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + item);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say "won't sort", what do you mean? Do you get an incorrect result? Does the program go into an infinite loop? Does the program crash?

Comment: Explain this one to the rubber duck: `if (arr[left] == arr[right]) return right;` Note that `left < right` here so you're not done partitioning yet.

Comment: Hey Jim, thank you for asking a clarifying question. The non-duplicate numbers sort normally, and any duplicates either get left where they started in the array at the incorrect place, or they get pushed to the very back. 
For Example: [2,5,4,2,8] becomes [2,4,5,8,2]
this doesn't happen for every array, but often enough that it's a problem.